# Instagram api response with empty data array

Tags: api, instagram

My problem is that i get an empty array from instagram api. i made the app this week and i know its a sandbox app but the problem is that i'm testing it just on my instagram account. i can like my pictures using the api. but i get empty array when i try to get recent tags, follower or followed-by even if i'm using the new scope `follower_list`
this is the array that i get:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [pagination] => stdClass Object
        (
        )
    [meta] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 200
        )
    [data] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instagram require you to submit your app for "review and approval" to gain access to non-basic permission scopes (eg accessing media from other users).

Their docs on this are here >>  https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/